# parametrize a curve by arclength

Tags: differential-geometry

patrametrize by arclength the following curve V( $t, e^t,2e^t$). I tried to differentiate V and the find the integral of |V'|, but the equation was not easy for me to handle , i need a quick trick to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is to compute the arc length. Now given the patametrization $V=\{t,e^t,2 e^t\}$ you can compute the velocity  by differentiating the parametrization. The velocity is $V'=\{1,e^t,2 e^t\}$.  The arc length function from $t=0$ is:

\begin{equation}
s(t)=\int_0^t \sqrt{1²+e^{2 x}+4 e^{2 x}} dx= \int_0^t \sqrt{1+5 e^{2 x}} dx
\end{equation}

where
\begin{equation}
 \int \sqrt{1+5 e^{2 x}} dx= \sqrt{1+5 e^{2 x}} -arctanh{\sqrt{1+5 e^{2 x}}}
\end{equation}
Once you have the arc length you can write t as a function of s and reparametrize V.